# javascript object declaration using prototype(including case)

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use of 'prototype' vs. 'this' in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310870/use-of-prototype-vs-this-in-javascript)

I donot know why some developer use javascript prototype object exactly.
so, I made a sample code below.
one using prototype object, the other plain syntax.
what is difference btwn two of them?
Is there any benefit to use prototype syntax, the first case?

```
Car.prototype.engine_ = 'bmw';
Car.prototype.getEngine = function(){
  return this.engine_;
}
Car.prototype.setEngine = function(engine){
  this.engine_ = engine;
}
function Car(){

//....

}

    var myCar = new Car();
    myCar.getEngine();
    myCar.setEngine('benz');
    console.debug(myCar.getEngine());
```

vs

```
function Car(){
  this.engine_ = 'bmw';
  this.setEngine = function(engine){
    engine_ = engine;
  }
  this.getEngine = function() {
    return engine_;
  }

  //...

}

var myCar = new Car();
myCar.getEngine();
myCar.setEngine('benz');
console.debug(myCar.getEngine());
```

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310870/use-of-prototype-vs-this-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a difference. Using `prototype`, your property or method is declared once in the Object and the same for all instances. Using direct properties/methods, these properties and method are added to every instance of the Object. So here's your Car constructor:

```
function Car(){this.engine = 'no known engine'};
Car.prototype.setEngine = function(val){
  this.engine = val;
}
```

Now the method `setEngine` is equal to all instances of your Car, but the `engine` property can vary per instance. The prototypal methods are defined once and looked up via the prototype chain ([see also this](http://mckoss.com/jscript/object.htm)). In this case `setEngine` sets the 'engine' property of *the current instance* of your Car. So you can do:

```
var bmw = new Car, merc = new Car;
bmw.setEngine('BMW');
merc.setEngine('Mercedes');
console.log(bmw.engine); //=> 'BMW'
console.log(merc.engine); //= 'Mercedes'
```

Comment: thank you for your simple clarification, kooilnc~

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no difference between this ones

Comment: you know wrong my dear friend - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310870/use-of-prototype-vs-this-in-javascript time to catch up on fundamentals behind the language! :)